# alter database move datafile throws ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: oracle

This is the code:

```
alter database move datafile '+DATA/axnnlp/datafile/users.261.863877097' 
to '+nl_data/axnnlp/datafile/users';*
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

I cannot find the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to use the `rename file` clause:

```
ALTER DATABASE
RENAME FILE '+DATA/axnnlp/datafile/users.261.863877097' -- Here!
TO '+nl_data/axnnlp/datafile/users' ;
```

Comment: No I tried exactly the command provided below. C&P from a Metalink document http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OSTMG/GUID-CF6CB742-9DCD-4211-8A45-3C0B48AB6FBE.htm#OSTMG95680

Comment: No I tried exactly the command provided below. C&P from a Metalink document http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OSTMG/GUID-CF6CB742-9DCD-4211-8A45-3C0B48AB6FBE.htm#OSTMG95680

Comment: @juniordba AFAIK this syntax was only introduced in 12c